# Is KSQL state queryable from Kafka Streams application?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Is it possible to query a KSQL KTable by key from a separate KStreams application? Or, in other words, is KSQL local state queryable through writing another application?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an open issue on ksql github

Comment: Is this the issue you're referring to? https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/530

Comment: Looks like it. Or just search for "interactive queries"

Comment: I see that this is in the pipe as a new natively functionality of KSQL: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/3117. 
However, what I was wondering was whether its possible to access the key-value store of the KSQL KTable (stored in RocksDB) from another Kafka Streams application. My goal is to do fast value lookup in RocksDB by key, as a work-around.

Comment: 3117 is just documentation. AFAIK, there is no such exposed api for that, and it's all still up for discussion. If you already are using Kafka Streams, then you'd need to rebuild that rocksdb locally in order to do key lookups, and just let ksql build the underlying topic

Comment: That is not possible. A KSQL server and a Kafka Streams application are completely isolated.